# I am new in coding so please help to solve this issue. As I attached a photo. After the last card I need some space that I cant do

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9R2l.png)
I need some space after the last card so please help me with that.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow :) Please visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and I suggest you re-take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [how to properly ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order to better assist you, could you provide us with the code you're working with ?

Comment: Hey man, welcome to SO. Please read and take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) around Stack Overflow. And, could you put some HTML code, so we can see whats going on here, that would be great

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the limited amount I can see I would guess that you should be using display flex. Something like this

```
div.glowingBoxesContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
div.glowingBoxesContainer div.glowingBox{
    width: calc(33.33% - 30px); //this will take into consideration margins
    margin: 15px;
    min-width: 300px;//this will force it to wrap if 33% is smaller than 300px
}
```